# Where is all this information coming from?

Tags: stocks, online-data-source, online-tools, online-trading

Hey everyone I'm a software developer and I have barely understood the financial world but here I am asking about the information that's available in most of the financial tools you can find at these websites you all use as your daily tools, such as
"TradingView.com" "Investing.com"

Like when you guys open your portfolios "Watch list" or "Holdings" you can see like 4 or 5 tables depending on the portfolio type.

```
Such as in "Watch list"
Table Price
Table Fundamental
Table Technical
Table Performance
Charts Candlestick Patterns
```

```
And in "Holdings"
Table Summary
Table Price
Table Fundamental
Table Technical
Table Performance
Charts Candlestick Patterns
```

I would like to know where this data is coming from.

For example, I can build my charts using python with a couple of lines and build some Candlesticks with OHCL data format, using Yahoo RapidAPI `"rapidapi.com/stock/v2/get-historical-data"` this is what they call `"Endpoints"`

What other data do I need in order to create my own Tables like the ones available at these 2 websites I previously mentioned?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ultimately, the data is *created* at stock exchanges. So you can get the data from the exchanges (good luck with that) or from someone else who gets it from the exchanges and forwards it to you (for a small cost probably).

Comment: Looks like you're not very familiar with the topic sir, this data comes from APIs such as ```rapidapi```, ```bloomberg```, etc.. However, there's several "endpoints" or "methods" to pull data from them, I'm expecting that someone knows the "endpoints" for "standard" financial tools offered by several trading platforms, I will reverse engineer their tools and data sources and I expected that someone in this stack knows about this topic. I don't need luck, I need knowledge and experience and time pays with those currencies. Good day.

Comment: Yes. RapidAPI and Bloomberg are people who get information from the exchanges and forward it to you.

Comment: Totally agree with that, do you know the "endpoints" related to those tables I'm talking about?

Comment: Are you asking how TradingView's software works and how it talks to Yahoo's API? That's not exactly a money question but a software question.

Comment: I know how they talk "via software" (APIs), I want to know to who they talk, much more like a "data" topic.

Comment: Well it sounds like you already know that TradingView talks to Yahoo RapidAPI